# How to implement a side-slide close page on the TargetPlatform.android?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

Flutter setting TargetPlatform.iOS

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Mian',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
    platform: TargetPlatform.iOS,
  )
)
```

Can skip the close page.

Flutter setting TargetPlatform.android

```
new MaterialApp(
  title: 'Mian',
  theme: new ThemeData(
    primarySwatch: Colors.orange,
    platform: TargetPlatform.android,
  )
)
```

Can‘t skip the close page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading the article I have new answers to update, this way is more friendly.

```
enter code class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
// This widget is the root of your application.
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
  title: 'Flutter Demo',
  theme: ThemeData(
      primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      pageTransitionsTheme: PageTransitionsTheme(builders: {
        TargetPlatform.android: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
        TargetPlatform.iOS: CupertinoPageTransitionsBuilder(),
      })),
  routes: {
    "/": (BuildContext context) =>
        MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    "/two": (BuildContext context) => TwoPage(),
  },
);
}
}
```

[image: Demo Gif]

Thanks to Arvinth for the article:https://medium.com/flutter-community/page-transitions-using-themedata-in-flutter-c24afadb0b5d

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using `CupertinoPageRoute` when you push the `Widget`.

First you have to import cupertino:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
```

Then use the `Navigator`:

```
Navigator.of(context)
            .push(CupertinoPageRoute(builder: (context) => YourNewWidgetPage()));
```